# Deleted ESP (EFI) partition - unable to create a new one

Tags: boot, uefi, boot-repair

I have an Asus Ultrabook UX32A.
I have a small SSD with 24 GB and a big HDD with 500 GB.
Windows 8 was pre-installed.
I deleted ALL Partitions on both discs (because I though I do not need any of them anymore) and installed Ubuntu 16.04.
I created a small partition at the beginning of the SSD and marked it in the installation process as efi.
On the remaining partition of the SSD, I installed Ubuntu 16.04.
After the installation, I was unable to boot into the new installed Ubuntu 16.04.
I tried Boot-Repair, but without any luck.

Boot-Repair Summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16309204/

I tried to reinstall the efi. I followed all steps from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi).

But if I mount the EFI partition in the live system (sudo mount /dev/sdb1 mnt/boot/efi), the EFI partition is completely empty.

Link to ubuntuforums.com: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323615&p=13484854#post13484854

Comment: Select the UEFI mode in the BIOS/UEFI settings, and reinstall.  Do not select some legacy or "compatibility" (CSM) mode.

Comment: It seems that you did not mark it to be used as an ESP.  Try again, and just pick the "install using the whole disk" option, which will do this for you.

Comment: I tried again. I deleted all partitions from the disc.
Then I installed Ubuntu on the small 24 GB SSD without any custom edits of the partitions.
After I restart, I can see for 1 second a message "failed to open \EFI\BOOT\MokManager.efi" and then my ASUS opens directly the Firmware settings.

Comment: See comments in ubuntuforums. You have to have either a bios_grub partition for grub to install correctly for BIOS boot, or an ESP - efi system partition on sda. The ESP on sdb will not be used by Ubuntu's version of grub.

Answer (score 0):

You have neither an [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) nor a [BIOS Boot Partition.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_Boot_partition) One of the two is required (well, almost required) to boot from a GPT disk. If you don't understand these details, you should let the Ubuntu installer set up your partitions for you. If you want to learn more, I recommend you read:

- **[Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)** -- This page describes the theory behind EFI-mode booting.
- **[A question and answers on the differences between BIOS and EFI booting on Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi)** -- This provides the basics of the preceding, but is more concise.
- **[My page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)** -- This page is a more practical introduction to EFI-mode booting than Adam Williamson's blog.
- **[The Ubuntu community wiki entry on UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)** -- This page is a bit disjointed, but is the most Ubuntu-specific introduction to EFI and its issues.

Answer (score 0):

Many users forget to add ubuntu as a trusted efi boot.  You need to do this in the Bios setup after install.  If this solves your problem, make a complaint and file a bug to Ubuntu for not telling you and the rest of the world to do this on the install screen.

If you do not add this file to your bios (The bios will prompt you where the file is), the computer will not boot.  This is the whole design of secure boot.  Of course it is useless if you do not protect your bios settings (which is very dangerous if you forget your pwd), because anyone can go into bios and change the boot and secure boot file.. or even better, boot legacy.  If your disk is not encrypted, then it is fair game.

However, I think you should read the links about efi and maybe your settings on the partition are not correct.  You should allocate about 400 to 500 mb.  The older computers only had 100mb which is not enough and it will fail to write and install file later on.  You can google the complaints on the size too, especially dual boots and going to win 10 (!) on a single boot system.

Comment: I disabled secure boot in the BIOS settings (the menu which you can enter by pressing F2 during startup).
But anyway, how can I add ubuntu as a trusted efi boot?

Comment: that does not do the trick.  You need to setup the file.  Create a password on your bios and you will get more menu items.  Then you will see add trusted file, at least in my acer.  (I later went legacy for dual boot easier relief).  BE SURE TO SET YOUR PASSWORD BACK TO NOTHING before you forget the pwd.  If you forget, you are doomed.